# How to pass variable of Python to bash code within same Python Program?

Tags: python, bash

I have written a python code to check if file exists in Hadoop file system or not. Python function receives location passed from another function and bash code within checks if location exists.

```
    def check_file_exists_in_hadoop(loc):
        yourdir = "/somedirectory/inhadoop/"+loc
        cmd = '''
        hadoop fs -test -d ${yourdir};
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]
        then 
            echo "Directory exists!"
        else
            echo "Directory does not exists!" 
        fi
        '''
        res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        output = (str(res, "utf-8").strip())
        print(output)
        if output == "Directory exists!":
            print("Yay!!!!")
        else:
            print("Oh no!!!!")
```

How to pass 'yourdir' variable inside bash portion of code.

Answer (score 3):

All that playing around in shells looks awkward, why not just do:

```
def check_file_exists_in_hadoop(loc):
    path = "/somedirectory/inhadoop/" + loc
    res = subprocess.run(["hadoop", "fs", "-test", "-d", path])
    return res.returncode == 0
```

You can execute as:

```
if check_file_exists_in_hadoop('foo.txt'):
    print("Yay!!!!")
else:
    print("Oh noes!!!!")
```

When you execute/run a process/program in a Unix-like system, it receives an array of arguments (exposed as e.g., `sys.argv` in Python).  you can construct these in various ways but passing them to `run` gives you the most direct control.  You can of course use a shell to do this, but starting up a shell just to do this seems unnecessary.  Given that this argument list is just a list of strings in Python you can use normal list/string manipulations to construct whatever you need.

Using a shell can be useful, but as Gilles says you need to be careful to sanitise/escape your input — not everybody loves [little bobby tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the string as an argument to the shell. Instead of using `shell=True`, which runs `['sh', '-c', cmd]` under the hood, invoke a shell explicitly. After the shell code, the first argument is the shell or script name (which is unused here), then the next argument is available as `"$1"` in the shell snippet, the next argument as `"$2"`, etc.

```
cmd = '''
    hadoop fs -test -d "$1";
…
'''
res = subprocess.check_output(['sh', '-c', cmd, 'sh', yourdir])
```

Alternatively, pass the string as an environment variable.

```
cmd = '''
    hadoop fs -test -d "$yourdir";
…
'''
env = os.environ.copy()
env['yourdir'] = yourdir
res = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, env=env)
```

In the shell snippet, note the [double quotes around `$1` or `$yourdir`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Do not interpolate the string into the shell command directly, i.e. don't use things like <strike>`'test -d {}'.format(yourdir)`</strike>. That doesn't work if the string contains shell special characters: it's a gaping security hole. For example if `yourdir` is `a; rm -rf ~` then you've just kissed your data goodbye.